# Swiftmailer Symfony 3 : 1 email sent but nothing appear

Tags: swiftmailer

I'm trying to send an email with symfony 3, swiftmailer and twig. 
I'm doing a form with formbuilder and when someone click on the submit button, it send the mail. I don't have an error, only a "1 spooled message".

What I've tried : I did : `php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send`
It returns : [OK] 1 emails were successfully sent. (also here i've no mail).
In my two boxes I have allowed less restrictions for connexions.

My code looks like : 
For the controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("testmail", name="testmail")
 */
public function testmail(Request $request)
{

    $societe = null;
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('Societe', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Société'), array('constraints' => array(new NotBlank(array()),
            new Length(array('min' => 2,
                'max' => 25)))))
        -> add('send',SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Cotation'))

        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $societe = $form["Societe"]->getData();

            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Etude Financiere')
                ->setFrom('wolffvianney@gmail.com')
                ->setTo('vianney.wolff@yahoo.fr')
                ->setCharset('utf-8')
                ->setContentType('text/html')
                ->setBody($this->render('@gkeep/Finance/email.html.twig', array('Societe' => $societe)));

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);


        }
    }

    return $this->render('@gkeep/Finance/finance.html.twig', array('form' =>$form->createView(),
    'Societe'=>$societe));


}
```

the config.yml :

```
swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
username: '%mailer_user%'
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: { type: memory }
```

the parameters.yml :

```
mailer_transport: mail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: wolffvianney@gmail.com
mailer_password: *mypasswordforwolffvianney@gmail.com*
secret: thesecret
```

the Finance/email.html.twig

```
<html>
hi
société : {{ Societe }}
</html>
```

if anyone has any advices or help, I can send other files if needed. I don't understand what is wrong, thanks for advance. (I also tried to delete the line       `spool{type:memory`
it says then that 1 email has been sent but here also, I don't receive any mails.

Vianney

Comment: Don't you have any errors ? Can you dump $societe after the line `$societe = $form["Societe"]->getData();`

Comment: No I don't get any error. It seems that all looks fine. I can dump, I can get the date of Societe. When I press the submit button I see under it the value of societe because I've wrote : `{%  if Societe is not null %}
        Société : {{ Societe }}

    {% endif %} `

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env={your_env}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I tried your line with dev env and it returns that 0 emails sent. :/

Comment: It may be possible than your emails are in the spam folder of your mail

Comment: I've just looked but no, there isn't :/